# Visual Studio code Terminal - TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

Tags: visual-studio-2010, terminal, syntax-error, execute

hi i have a **problem** im using **visual studio code** and the terminal shows **TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined** thanks

can someone help - [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax2Ra.png

```
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
    if (command == 'youtube'){
        client.commands.get('youtube').execute(message, args);
    }
    if (command == 'instagram'){
        client.commands.get('instagram').execute(message, args);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line:

```
if (command === 'ping'){
    client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
}
```

to this line:

```
if (command == 'ping'){
    client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
(command === 'ping')
```

to

```
(command == 'ping')
```

Comment: all i had to do was remove = 5 hours trying to fix this XD thx

Comment: Do hit up the answer then xP